# Submitting to Apple with an earlier deployment target than current build

Tags: ios, iphone, deployment, target

We have a project where we want to release the next version of an app with a deployment target of iOS 6+, but then release a further update afterwards with a deployment target of iOS 5.1+ (despite the fact only 2-3% of users on iOS 5)

Is this possible?

To clarify:

Version 1.0 is currently live in the app store, targeting iOS 5.1+ (released over a year ago)

Version 2.0 is ready and targets iOS 6.0+, but has a number of known bugs for iOS 5.1 users.  The client wants to release this ASAP without the bug fixes, and work on these after release.

So can we release version 2.0 but only target iOS 6+, and then release version 2.1 with fixes for iOS 5.1 and set that as the target?  Or will Apple not allow a new build to target a lower OS version?

We've tried researching this online but yielding no results, does anyone known specifically if this can be done?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not aware of there being any issue with this technically. You can certainly change the Deployment Target to a later version, apps do that all of the time. And I can't imagine it being a problem supporting more versions. But it's a pretty lousy thing to do to your customers. Take a few days and fix the bugs now.

Comment: Ask the experts: :)  Apple

Comment: Did you work out a definitive answer to this? If you did could you share it here please.